Shadcn.ui popover element including commands in Next.Js 14: can't select/click the elements with the mouse
I'm trying to evaluate the ease of use the shadcn.ui component library. I'm trying to implement a popover component as this:
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Command, CommandEmpty, CommandGroup, CommandInput, CommandItem, CommandList, CommandSeparator } from "@/components/ui/command";
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover";
import { CalendarIcon, EnvelopeClosedIcon, FaceIcon, GearIcon, PersonIcon, RocketIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons";

export function PopoverDemo() {
  return (
    <Popover>
      <PopoverTrigger asChild>
        <Button variant="outline">Open popover</Button>
      </PopoverTrigger>
      <PopoverContent className="w-80">
        <Command className="rounded-lg border shadow-md">
          <CommandInput placeholder="Type a command or search..." />
          <CommandList>
            <CommandEmpty>No results found.</CommandEmpty>
            <CommandGroup heading="Suggestions">
              <CommandItem>
                <CalendarIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                <span>Calendar</span>
              </CommandItem>
              <CommandItem>
                <FaceIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                <span>Search Emoji</span>
              </CommandItem>
              <CommandItem>
                <RocketIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                <span>Launch</span>
              </CommandItem>
            </CommandGroup>
            <CommandSeparator />
            <CommandGroup heading="Settings">
              <CommandItem>
                <PersonIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                <span>Profile</span>
              </CommandItem>
              <CommandItem>
                <EnvelopeClosedIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                <span>Mail</span>
              </CommandItem>
              <CommandItem>
                <GearIcon className="mr-2 h-4 w-4" />
                <span>Settings</span>                
              </CommandItem>
            </CommandGroup>
          </CommandList>
        </Command>
      </PopoverContent>
    </Popover>
  );
}

the main page:
import { PopoverDemo } from "@/components/PopoverDemo";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <PopoverDemo></PopoverDemo>
    </div>
  );
}


I'm trying to mimic the behavior that is on the "tasks" example seen on the Demo section. This is a mix between the Command component and the Popover component.
I'm able to open the popover. it is possible to select one command element with the keyboard, but I'm not able to select or click any of the components with the mouse. It feels like the command component is disabled

Am I missing something ? Thanks for your help

The Command Component from shadcn.ui is relying on the "cmdk" library. In the Github repository for Shacn.ui, the version for cmdk is 0.2.0, see the package.json file. When you first install the component, it will automatically install the cmdk version 1.0.0. This is breaking the component. I don't know if there is an ARIA option coming with version 1.0.0 that would allow to enable the command component inside another component

Command component do not have its own state so we need to provide state with help of useState.
You can follow below example from documentation:
import * as React from "react"
import { CaretSortIcon, CheckIcon } from "@radix-ui/react-icons"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
  Command,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandInput,
  CommandItem,
} from "@/components/ui/command"
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/popover"

const frameworks = [
  {
    value: "next.js",
    label: "Next.js",
  },
  {
    value: "sveltekit",
    label: "SvelteKit",
  },
  {
    value: "nuxt.js",
    label: "Nuxt.js",
  },
  {
    value: "remix",
    label: "Remix",
  },
  {
    value: "astro",
    label: "Astro",
  },
]

export function ComboboxDemo() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("")

  return (
    <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
      <PopoverTrigger asChild>
        <Button
          variant="outline"
          role="combobox"
          aria-expanded={open}
          className="w-[200px] justify-between"
        >
          {value
            ? frameworks.find((framework) => framework.value === value)?.label
            : "Select framework..."}
          <CaretSortIcon className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
        </Button>
      </PopoverTrigger>
      <PopoverContent className="w-[200px] p-0">
        <Command>
          <CommandInput placeholder="Search framework..." className="h-9" />
          <CommandEmpty>No framework found.</CommandEmpty>
          <CommandGroup>
            {frameworks.map((framework) => (
              <CommandItem
                key={framework.value}
                value={framework.value}
                onSelect={(currentValue) => {
                  setValue(currentValue === value ? "" : currentValue)
                  setOpen(false)
                }}
              >
                {framework.label}
                <CheckIcon
                  className={cn(
                    "ml-auto h-4 w-4",
                    value === framework.value ? "opacity-100" : "opacity-0"
                  )}
                />
              </CommandItem>
            ))}
          </CommandGroup>
        </Command>
      </PopoverContent>
    </Popover>
  )
}

Note: It seems like you have only links in your CommandItem(s) so you have to just close the popover in this case with use of setOpen

I'm sorry, but your code does not work on my side. Moreover, I don't understand why we do have to use state. In the git hub repository of shadcn, in the task example, they clearly don't need to use this.

We need to use useState to store the selected CommandItems value

Ok, I see your point, but this is not what I'm trying to test. I think I found the reason why this is not working. the Command Component from shadcn.ui is relying on the "cmdk" library. In the Github repository for Shacn.ui, the package for cmdk is version 0.2.0... while mine is automatically 1.0

You basically need a  wrapper after your . this has happened due to cmdk releasing 1.0 with these breaking changes.
also you would need to replace data-[disabled] with data-[disabled='true'] in the className for whichever element uses that class attribute relating to cmdk, to avoid having cmdk be disabled.
